# Javascript/HTML5 canvas redrawing

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have an average-sized "world", a 2D plane containing visible objects. If displayed in full, it's dimensions would be at least around 2000x2000 pixels. However, only a part of it is drawn into the screen in a canvas(640x480) called "view". The user can move the view around this world.

The current strategy I use is to draw the visible objects in a same-sized(640x480) in-memory canvas, then redraw it to the view every time it is moved.

However, the world, objects, and their positions do not change. In effect, it can be thought of as a single large image.

Is it better to have a 2000x2000(or more) buffer canvas, then draw part of it to the visible canvas? Or should I stick to my current strategy: have a 640x280 buffer and draw only the visible objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the world is updated every frame. This implies the world needs to be re-rendered every frame since the position may have changed.

Looking out of a performance perspective, I'd rather have the game loop check which objects are visible and only draw those, rather than render the whole world and pick that 640x480 pixel area.

Depending on your implementation, you may also want to draw objects that are "almost" visible, if the movement of the view (camera) is rather speedy.

I'd suggest you do something like:

- Have a single 640x480 canvas
- Have a virtual world size of 2000x2000 pixels
- Have your game render everything to the context, then transform the context to the camera position, then render 640x480 pixels starting from this point.
- Your "world" would then be static, but the camera will move around and "looking" at a point to render